# How do I change a username? (shortname and home folder)

Tags: macos

Under Linux, this would be a no brainer. Just go into /etc/password and edit that, and rename the directory in /home. 
I want the new shortname and the new home folder to match after the change.

Comment: Just a side note: in Linux it not so straightforward. You also have to update `/etc/group`, eventual mail alias (e.g., username@machine)  and all the places where your old username is present (usually many).

Answer (score 7):

Apple's own instructions work quite well. There may be more complex and faster ways out there, but I've never run into an issue (such as incorrect permissions) with these steps.

[Mac OS X v10.6 and earlier: How to change user account name or home directory name](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1428)

Comment: This is certainly the "official" way to go - but it has two drawbacks: The big one, is you end up with a different UID. It's not a big deal, but for most people, keeping user number 501 is the least hassle when connecting an external drive to another mac. The other is it's longer than needed. I presume Apple decided to have a much longer process to avoid telling someone to delete a user account since some people will not read things and end up deleting everything - potentially without a backup.

Comment: I did not realize the bit about the UID - haven't run into a problem regarding the UID, but it's certainly something to consider.

Comment: This worked fine for me, thanks. I thought it would be harder.

Answer (score 3):

In **System Preferences**, **Users & Groups**, right click the username in the list on the left and select **Advanced Options**. Edit the **Account name** field and click **Ok**.

Ideally you'll also want to edit the **Home directory** to match the new username, although this isn't strictly necessary.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: How do we change the home directory to match the username? Renaming it in finder doesn't seem to work

Comment: Ingmar Hupp is referring to the dialog box that appears when you select "Advanced Options."

Answer (score 1):

I really don't like to edit a user in place since it's so simple to delete the user (preserving the home folder) - rename the folder as root - make the new user with the correct short name matching the renamed folder.

The preference pane will see that you already have /Users/newshort and offer to inherit the folder. It does the best job I know of in setting ownership and correcting the ACL needed for your home folder to work as Apple intended.

---

1. Check your backup is current - ***just in case***
2. Do the delete
   [image]
3. Do the move in terminal `sudo -s` followed by `mv /Users/tester\ \(Deleted\)/ /Users/test`
4. Do the create
   [image]

Comment: You should *probably* run the "Repair Permissions" task in Disk Utility after performing this action. Since the Unix user ID will be different after deleting and creating a new user.

Comment: Repair Permissions never touches a user home folder. It only fixes software that Apple has installed by looking at /Library/Receipts (or the newer receipts database) - the user permissions are only set by the preference pane / dscl / open directory that's new in Lion.